# Ignore pagebreak at some pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I need to have no empty lines at some pages of the document.
The reason for it is that I'm putting a table on some pages that is pretty long, and I used scalign `\scalebox` and `\centerline` for it, but I can't make it any smaller, since it won't be readable. What i mean is that I have empty lines at the top of the page, then my table right to the end of it, and I have page number inserted inside the table (and I want not to have it, but can't remove numbering on the entire doc. It's necessary).

If you can't imagine it, here's a screenshot:

[image: You can see there is 9 as it's a page number]

Comment: Perhaps a mere `\thispagestyle{empty}` would do. You could also consider inserting a (page-breakable) [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`longtable` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable), which allows you to let your table break across the page boundary.

The interface is slightly different from that of a regular `tabular`, but this is to accommodate the user's view on a table that spans more than one page (repetition of header, for example).